Adding colums to a yfinance dataframe from an excel file in python
I'm having problems adding colums of data to a dataframe of data downloaded using yfinance. The colums of data come from an Excel file. The most important thing is that I have to keep the same shape and layout of the yfinance dataframe in terms of tickers and dates.
DESIRED LAYOUT
What is the code to fix that issue?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
